# How to tell Azure Web App where server.js is

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have a yml file setup with Github actions while it deploys Azure doesn't actually serve the site correctly. It states in the Azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux#run-with-pm2) that the container will start with one of the common files:

> bin/www

> server.js

> app.js

> index.js

> hostingstart.js

My folder structure looks like this:

- dist

  - server.js
  - ...
- build

  - ...
- node_modules

  - ...

If I move /dist into the root the express server initiates and begins trying to serve routes but blows up due to the folder structure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please refer to the [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsaPh7-YA9Q)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify server.js file. You can find it following this path:

1. Configuration
2. General Settings
3. Startup Command
4. Type "./dist/server.js"

Comment: wow. way to hijack some creds there :/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Startup Command set within the Configuration -> General Settings page ?

If not, you can use this to provide optional command(s) to control how your instance starts.

You use this when you deviate from the standard its expecting.

Comment: Ok, I got this working, if you can just edit your answer to say, "Go to Configuration -> General Settings: Startup Command" and enter "./dist/server.js" this does fix the issue and I'll mark it as the answer to give you the bounty. Thank YOU!!! Also, it's probably worth adding in Azure CLI solution of: `az webapp config set --resource-group <name> --name <app name> --startup-file "./dist/server.js"`